# Guild banners, influence bonus and activation

Tags: guild-wars-2

In the guild panel, it is possible to craft some stuff. For example, I created a Karma banner. I get that it will be placed in any location I choose to activate it, and that guild members can click on it.

It is stated that this last 30 minutes. I guess this mean any member touching the banner get a buff for that 30 min. Does it also mean the banner expires after 30 minutes? What if another member comes to the banner afterwards, can he get the 30 min bonus? What if I come back before my own buff expires, is it possible to refresh it?

There are other upgrades like the "+5% Influence for 24 Hrs". Do they auto-activate at the end of the build, or are those manual too?

Comment: Banners are one shot deals. You craft them, use them, and then they are gone until you craft another one. Not sure on the usage, as we've not used ours yet :)

Comment: I can confirm clicking on the banner again will refresh the buff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The banner lasts for one hour, and the buff that you can get from it also lasts for 30 minutes. This buff can be refreshed by touching the banner again before it disappears.

All consumables created from influence will become available upon completion rather than activate upon completion.

Also, not only can your guild members use your guild's banners, but any players that touch it can (not including opposing players in WvW).